# how to handle URL with dot extension file redirect particular component angular 5

Tags: angular, iis

how to handle url with dot extension (eg.vpf) in angular 5.Application redirect http 404 page. i need redirect particular app component. I am using asp.net core angular 5 host with iis server

this sample url  structure 
https://localhost/News/TopNews/2018/04/07071142/Cauvery-River-Water-Issue-chief-Minister-to-consult.vpf

Comment: What is the point of this?  You want to tell the browser that you are downloading some random filetype, only to trick it and download an angular route instead?  Or are you trying to tell the browser that your angular app is actually sending a Vector Product Format file instead of HTML/JavaScript?

Comment: I need url ends with dot extension (eg.vpf ) angular app routes with  detail-component. without using .vpf extension application works fine. pls tell any one how to redirect this detail-component angular 5 using iis

Comment: You are avoiding the question of **why this is necessary**. This isn’t really something angular was designed to handle, as this is dealing with browser behavior outside angular control.  Without understanding why this is necessary, it is very difficult to formulate a workaround.